# Windows 7 constantly forgets my dual-monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with a 1680x1050 resolution and another screen with a 1920x1080 resolution. Everytime I reboot Windows, my screens change to a common (lower) resolution and mirror instead of extend. How can I make Windows remember that they should be extended instead of mirroring?

Comment: This may sound a bit extraneous, but if changing drivers did not help your issue, and you have a service running called: Windows Live Mesh remote connections service; try disabling it. That’s what finally worked for me!

Comment: This is a known issue. Disabling Live Mesh seems to solve it in a majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and trying what Mitchell suggested in his comment helped.

I disabled Live Mesh remote connections (didn't have to uninstall the software) and on the next restart my screen resolution stayed at what I configured.